# Upgrade php 5.5.* to php 5.6.* using apt-get

Tags: php, debian, apt-get

I installed a new local server, when I installed php5 package with `apt-get install php5` it got the version 5.6.

My production server is still with php 5.5 and I would like to upgrade it to php 5.6 like in my dev environment.

Can I do it easily using apt-get ? tell to apt-get to switch to the branch 5.6 ?

Thx

Comment: Doing a `phpinfo()` on your local server will give you the configure command (among other things) which you can use to compile PHP from source. I find this way much better in replicating configurations between environments.

Comment: Yeah but I want to use apt-get to update easily

Comment: Trust me, if it's not the native `apt-get` supplied version, it's not that easy. Maybe you can get the right PHP version but the wrong extensions.

Comment: Can you give me the specific phpinfo property ?

Comment: 3rd property of `phpinfo()` is the configure command. You can do `./configure....` in the folder with the php source, and then `make`, `make install`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enter the following commands in the order shown:

```
apt-get -y update
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
apt-get -y update
```

`apt-get -y install php5.6 php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-mbstring php5.6-curl` `php5.6-cli php5.6-mysql php5.6-gd php5.6-intl php5.6-xsl`

Enter the following command to verify PHP 5.6 installed properly:

```
php -v
```

Following is a sample response that indicates PHP 5.6 is installed:

```
PHP 5.6.22-4+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

Done+

Answer (score 2):

To upgrade to a newer version of PHP 5.6 on Ubuntu 14.04, you can use [Ondřej Surý's](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5-5.6) PPA. He is one of the Debian maintainers of the php5 package. To add the PPA and upgrade your packages, run:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install php5
```

Comment: `Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct`

Comment: @Jadeye try `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` then `sudo apt-get install -y php5.6`

Comment: @Jadeye You can get help from this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40567133/cannot-add-ppa-ppaondrej-php5-5-6

Comment: @subs I tried everything I could find, still I could never install `php5.6`, couldn't find the reason why!

Comment: @Jadeye what version of Ubuntu are you running? I went to install 5.6 the other day on ubuntu 14.04 but it is no longer supported - as of quite recently. Had to upgrade my ubuntu version so that I could install php 5.6

Comment: @subs yes that seems to be the issue `14.04`

Answer (score 1):

For PHP 5.6

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
```

For PHP 5.5

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
```

[Reference](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5)

Comment: When I will run an `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`, the newest version of php5.6 will be installed (like in my dev server) ?

Comment: Execute that once you've told apt which repo to use with the command that I've given you above, then yes

Answer (score 1):

I know that it's a little late to answer this question , but for anyone like me who is confused when upgrading php , I should say please note that before installing new version of php remove it completely from your system, even remove config files and extensions, It caused me so many errors and problems.

```
 sudo apt-get purge php.*
 sudo rm -rf /etc/php5
 sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get upgrade
 sudo apt-get install php5
```

Comment: Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.