# Couldn't find any package by regex 'php5.6'

Tags: php, apt-get

I am trying to upgrade from PHP 5.5.38 to PHP 5.6. I am following instructions [available on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38737323/520957), but I am getting the following error messages:

```
sudo apt-get -y install php5.6 php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-mbstring php5.6-curl php5.6-cli php5.6-mysql php5.6-gd php5.6-intl php5.6-xsl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php5.6
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php5.6'
E: Unable to locate package php5.6-mcrypt
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php5.6-mcrypt'
E: Unable to locate package php5.6-mbstring
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php5.6-mbstring'
E: Unable to locate package php5.6-curl
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php5.6-curl'
E: Unable to locate package php5.6-cli
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php5.6-cli'
E: Unable to locate package php5.6-mysql
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php5.6-mysql'
E: Unable to locate package php5.6-gd
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php5.6-gd'
E: Unable to locate package php5.6-intl
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php5.6-intl'
E: Unable to locate package php5.6-xsl
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php5.6-xsl'
```

Does anyone know what is causing this issue?

**P.S.**: I am on Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)

Comment: Are you sure that Ondrej's PPA was added successfully?

Comment: @Mjh: I performed the command. How can I check that?

Comment: After running the commands you found on the linked article, what did your terminal say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the proper instructions here: http://nwdthemes.com/2016/01/31/how-to-upgrade-to-php-5-6-on-debian-7-wheezy/