# Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6'

Tags: php, ubuntu

I'm trying to update my php 5.5.9 to 5.6 in an Ubuntu machine.

But when I run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
```

I'm getting:

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

How can I fix this?

### EDIT

I ran:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5
```

But when I run:

```
php5 -v
```

I still get php 5.5.9:

```
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20 (cli) (built: Oct  3 2016 13:00:37)
```

Comment: Add the right PPA: https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php. The one you're trying to get was deprecated

Comment: Thanks, i could install ppm, but not able to update php, I edited my answer. Can you help? @Clive

Comment: Hi, I am in ubuntu 14.04, and encountered the same issue, change your last cmd to "sudo apt-get install php5.6", then it works.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

add the right ppa first, do the following

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get -y install php5.6 php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-mbstring php5.6-curl php5.6-cli php5.6-mysql php5.6-gd php5.6-intl php5.6-xsl php5.6-zip`

i had the same issue in installing the php5.6 then i did the above steps.

Comment: step 2 & 4 both have `apt-get install php5.6`, which does not make sense. And after adding repo, you should always issue `apt-get update` to refresh the local repo list before installing anything.

Comment: yes you are right. we should use the apt-get update before install

Comment: Just in case, I had to run: LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

Comment: ERROR: '~ondrej' user or team does not exist

Answer (score 11):

While the answer of @tanveerahmaddar provides crucial information, here is the correct way to install the PHP 5.6 on Ubuntu 12.04:

> Important: If you plan to use PHP5.6 in websites (which you probably wish to), you have to upgrade to Apache 2.4, which does not ship with Ubuntu 12.04 (will cover the upgrade of Apache below)

**Step 1: Check versions**

```
# check PHP version
php -v
# check Apache version
apache2 -v
```

If your Apache version is 2.2, follow Step 2; if version is 2.4, skip to Step 3

**Step 2: Add PHP5.6+ repository and update package list**

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

This step will upgrade Apache from 2.2 to 2.4. Re-configure your Apache if needed. *Backup your existing Apache configurations, enabled sites and mods. You might need to re-install / upgrade some of the mods.*

**Step 3: Add PHP5.6+ Repository**

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
apt-get update
```

**Step 4: Install PHP 5.6**

```
apt-get install -y php5.6 php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-mbstring php5.6-curl php5.6-cli php5.6-mysql php5.6-gd php5.6-intl php5.6-xsl php5.6-zip libapache2-mod-php5.6
```

This will install PHP 5.6 and some common packages such as cURL (`php5.6-curl`) and GD (`lib5.6-gd`), as well as enable PHP 5.6 in Apache 2.4 (`libapache2-mod-php5.6`).

Apache will be restarted during the process.

That's all steps you have to do.

---

Hint: If you want to upgrade to PHP 7 instead (*off-topic*), just issue the following command after Step 3 (skip Step 4):

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

---

Final words: Not recommend to upgrade to PHP 5.6 in Ubuntu 12.04, as it involves upgrading Apache to 2.4. Ubuntu 14.04 comes with Apache 2.4, which is a lot easier to upgrade PHP 5.6.

Comment: why after i follow ur step, when i run script with phpinfo() i still get previous php version, yet when i run `php -v` through cli, i got php5.6

Comment: This is because your Apache is loading old PHP, as proven by the path of the `php.ini`  shown in `phpinfo()`. Although throughout the process Apache will restart itself, have you tried restarting the Apache service yourself and see whether Apache is still using the old version?

Comment: @slier: this happen because Apache still has loaded old PHP module. This is my solution (You need run all this command in this order):
`cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled; rm -fr php5.*; ln -s ../mods-available/php5.6.conf . ; ln -s ../mods-available/php5.6.load . ;/etc/init.d/apache2 restart;`

Comment: This command can be probably replaced by `a2enmod/a2dismod` but I'm not familiar with it.

Answer (score 6):

This work for perfectly for me.
Add the right PPA first, by doing the following

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install php5.6 php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-mbstring php5.6-curl 
php5.6-cli php5.6-mysql php5.6-gd php5.6-intl php5.6-xsl php5.6-zip
```

Disable php 5.5.3 or 5.5.9 module

```
a2dismod php5
```

Enable the just installed php5.6 module

```
a2enmod php5.6
```

Finally, you restart your apache

```
sudo service apache restart
```

@tanveer ahmad dar highlighted most of it.

Comment: Also, if you have to check versions, then use "php5.6 -v" instead of "php5 -v".

Comment: True, "php5.6 -h" or "php -h" will give you more options too @Filipe Ferminiano

Answer (score 2):

This worked in my Ubuntu Server 14.04.5 LTS

```
a2dismod php5
a2enmod php5.6
apache2ctl restart
```