# phpversion() function and `php -version` on terminal returning different results

Tags: php, installation, upgrade

I just upgraded my PHP version from `PHP 5.59` to `PHP 6` by following this answer
[Upgrade php 5.5.* to php 5.6.* using apt-get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568374/upgrade-php-5-5-to-php-5-6-using-apt-get)

But I am getting a strange problem `PHP -version` on terminal result in

```
PHP 5.6.34-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

but `phpversion()` is still retuning the old version which is

```
5.5.9-1ubuntu4.24
```

Comment: is it possible ? how can I print all installed php versions using terminal

Comment: Do you mean on the CLI you have one version and via your web server a different one?  Perhaps restart your web-service.

Comment: not CLI, on my terminal I am accessing my server through a terminal using SSH.

Comment: Or rather, specifically, how are you executing `phpversion()` ?

Comment: check your ubuntu path variable to ensure that your php call on cli is with the right version. Maybe you have two different versions installed.

Comment: @KuldeepDangi yes it is possible to have two different versions simultaneously

Comment: executing phpversion() through a web script, on browser.

Comment: Did you try to restart your web service?  (Something like `sudo service php-fpm restart`)

Comment: php-fpm is not registered as a service

Comment: Okay, how about `sudo service apache2 restart` or `sudo restart apache2`, guessing here, as I have no idea what your web stack is.

Comment: You have several php versions installed on your computer. Your webserver is using the 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.24 version.